# Laravel migration column year is not supported by doctrine

Tags: laravel, doctrine, laravel-migrations, dbal

I can't figure it out why in Laravel documentation we have

> $table->year('birth_year');  YEAR equivalent column.

But when I try to change a column type to year, I get this error:

```
   Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException 

  Unknown column type "year" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with
 \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use A
bstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or
 forgot some mapping information.

  at C:\test\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php:267
    263|      * @return \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
    264|      */
    265|     public static function unknownColumnType($name)
    266|     {
  > 267|         return new self('Unknown column type "' . $name . '" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has ' .
    268|             'to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the ' .
    269|             'known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database ' .
    270|             'introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use ' .
    271|             'AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement ' .

  1   C:\test\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TypeRegistry.php:30
      Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::unknownColumnType("year")

  2   C:\test\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type.php:231
      Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TypeRegistry::get("year")
```

here is my migration file content :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('entities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //
        $table->year('year_established')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

and my composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
},
```

and why there is nothing about this issue on the SO?! no one used this column type before?!

Comment: you can't change to every column type and you can't change every column type, there are limitations

Comment: @lagbox thank you. you mean this error is only for changing a column type not creating a column?